# Firebase "Site Not Found" error on some devices and not on others

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, firebase-hosting

When I open my Firebase hosted site (built with Polymer Starter Kit) using my computer that I deployed (i.e., using `$ firebase deploy`) the app from, it works great. It works on all browsers too.

However, when I try to open it on my mobile device (an Android tablet in this case) I get a Site Not Found Error. The full error text message reads as follows:

> Site Not Found
>
> Why am I seeing this?
>
> There are a few potential reasons:
>
> 1. You haven't deployed an app yet.
> 2. You may have deployed an empty directory.
> 3. This is a custom domain but we haven't finished setting it up yet.
>
> How can I deploy my first app?
>
> Refer to our hosting documentation to get started.

Obviously, none of the possible causes listed are actually the case because, as mentioned, the site tests fine on my deploying device. And on all browsers on that device.

### Question

**What could be causing this?**

Comment: That doesn't sound right, contact support@firebase.com.

Comment: Is it a new domain? Does your Android device use your WLan or connect to the web using the phone network?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: User error. Problem fixed.

I just tested it again and it worked on the other devices. Since I was not clicking a link, but rather, typing it instead, I think that was what caused the problem.

I think what happened was the "en dash" character on some soft keypads looks like a different character (maybe em dash?) which causes the typed URL not to match the actual URL if the user is not used to typing out URLs and doesn't know how to tell the difference on a soft keypad between the different types of dashes.